# Server Side Header Bidding

Tags: prebid.js

I have recently done project in client side header bidding using prebid.js,now how can I achieve server side header bidding,I have seen many articles but all give only explanation about server side header bidding,Can anyone give clear reference for that..! Any help appreciated